# getline not working as expected

Tags: c++, while-loop, text-files

I'm trying to display a text file data into columns using a class structure and getline() function to read through the textfile and the dump the data into a vector class. But it seems that the program didn't even run to my 'while' loop then quitting the program. The textfile is not empty.

Below is my code:

```
void ScrambleWordGame::displayScoreChart() {
//open file
fstream readScoreChart("ScoreChart.txt");
string line = "";

//vector to store data in
vector<personResult> perResult;
personResult person;

//while file is open, do stuff
if(readScoreChart.is_open())
{
    //check through the file
    readScoreChart.seekp(0,ios::end);
    //get the size of the file's data
    size_t size = readScoreChart.tellg();
    if(size == 0)
        cout << "No results yet. Please TRY to win a game. AT LEAST~" << endl;
    else
    {
        //create the 1st row with 4 column names
        cout << left
            << setw(20) << "Player Name "
            << setw(20) << "Winning Time "
            << setw(20) << "No. Of Attempts "
            << setw(20) << "Game Level " << endl;
        //fill the second line with dashes(create underline)
        cout << setw(70) << setfill('-') << "-" << endl;
        //read the file line by line
        //push the 1st line data into 'line'
        cout << getline(readScoreChart,line);
        while(getline(readScoreChart,line))
        {
            //create stringstream n push in the entire line in
            stringstream lineStream(line);

            //reads the stringstream and dump the data seperated by delimiter
            getline(lineStream,person.playerName,':');
            getline(lineStream,person.winningTime,':');
            getline(lineStream,person.noOfAttempts,':');
            getline(lineStream,person.gameLvl);

            //sort the results based on their timing
            //sort(perResult.begin(),perResult.end(),pRes);
            //display the results
            cout << left
                    << setfill(' ')
                    << setw(25) << person.playerName
                    << setw(22) << person.winningTime
                    << setw(17) << person.noOfAttempts
                    << setw(16) << person.gameLvl
                    << endl;
        }
    }
}
readScoreChart.close();
```

}

Edit: Example of the TextFile
Joel:3:1:1
Mary:5:2:2
John:25:3:1

Comment: Could you post a couple lines of the text file that you're trying to parse, please?

Comment: `readScoreChart.seekp(0,ios::end);` - the file may not be empty, but you are skipping over all the contents.

Comment: @Casey I'm doing that as to check whether the textfile is empty or not. After checking the pointer should be back at the top, isn't it?

Comment: no if you jump at the end you stay at the end until a call to seekp(0, iOS::begin)

Comment: @alexbuisson then where should i place the call for seekp?

Comment: perfect answer from @ogni42. if you use seeking to figure the file size it's a 3-step process, seek at the end, call tell, seek back at the beginning!

Comment: @alexbuisson "... a call to seekp(0, **iOS**::begin)" now I guess you have a smartphone with a fruit on the back <:o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file pointer is at the end of the file after your first seek. You need to reposition it to the beginning of the file.

```
if(size == 0)
{
    cout << "No results yet. Please TRY to win a game. AT LEAST~" << endl;
}
else
{
    readScoreChart.seekp(0,ios::begin);
    // all you other stuff
}
```

Comment: Now I can display the data from the text file. But now this '0x7fff52b710e0Mary' comes out in my output. Anyone know what's wrong with this?

Comment: Solves the problem, but I would rather put that second `seekp` just after the `tellg` (before testing `size`)

Comment: @gx I tend to make calls at the place where I need them for (i) the sake of efficiency and (ii) the sake of easier maintenance

Comment: @ogni42 That's a point, but IMO the whole operation of "getting the size" should let the pointer unchanged, i.e.: save the current position (unless you're sure it's the beginning) then: 1. seek to end; 2. tell position and store the size; 3. seek back to previous position (saved or beginning). All 3 calls at the same place (possibily _factorized in a function_). (But of course you can still add a `seekp(0,ios::begin)` each time you want to be sure to read the file from the beginning.)

Comment: Oh I hadn't noticed: "put that second **seekp** just after the **tellg**"... The code should pair either `seekp`/`tellp` (for an `ofstream`) or `seekg`/`tellg` (for an `ifstream`, and prefered for a `fstream` like here) of course

Comment: @ogni42 shouldn't it be ios::beg instead of iOS::begin?

Answer (score 1):

You need to seek back to the beginning of the file to be able to read. Better still, just don't seek to the end in the first place.

I'd re-structure the code a bit -- write an `operator>>` to read a record from a file, and an `operator<<` to write a record to a file.

```
class person {
    std::string name;
    std::string winning_time;
    std::string num_attempts;
    std::string level;

 public:
    bool operator<(person const &other) const { 
        return std::stoi(winning_time) < std::stoi(other.winning_time);
    }

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, person &p) { 
            std::string buffer;
            std::getline(in, buffer);
            std::istringstream is(buffer);

            std::getline(is,p.name,':');
            std::getline(is,p.winning_time,':');
            std::getline(is,p.num_attempts,':');
            std::getline(is,p.level);
            return in;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, person const &p) { 
             return os << std::setw(25) << p.name
                       << std::setw(22) << p.winning_time
                       << std::setw(17) << p.num_attempts
                       << std::setw(16) << p.level;
    }

};
```

With those in place, the rest gets quite a bit simpler:

```
void show_header(std::ostream &os) { 
    cout << left
        << setw(20) << "Player Name "
        << setw(20) << "Winning Time "
        << setw(20) << "No. Of Attempts "
        << setw(20) << "Game Level " << "\n";
    std::cout << std::string(70, '-');
}

 void game::displayScoreChart(){ 
    std::ifstream in("ScoreChart.txt");

    // read the data:
    std::vector<person> people{std::istream_iterator<person>(in),
                               std::istream_iterator<person>()};

   if (people.empty()) {
       std::cout << "No scores yet."
       return;
   }

   // sort it by winning time:
   std::sort(people.begin(), people.end());

   show_header(std::cout);

   // display it:
   for (auto const &p : people) 
       std::cout << p << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

As a simple replacement if you don't have a C++11 compiler, an `stoi` can be written something like this:

```
int stoi(std::string in) { 
     return strtol(in.c_str(), NULL, 10);
}
```

Comment: What does the stoi stands for?

Comment: @JoelSeah: "string to integer". Added in C++11 (but there are rough equivalents in C++03).

Comment: do i have to include that in the header?

Comment: @JoelSeah: you have to include `<string>`, but that's not new, since you're already using `std::strring`.

Comment: That error 'not declared in this scope' still persists. I'm using netbeans 7.3.1. could it be something wrong with my c++ version?

Comment: @JoelSeah: You're probably using a pre-C++11 compiler and need to update to something newer.

Comment: How do i check my compiler version on a MAC and any idea how i can do update?

Comment: @JoelSeah: Not much beyond "download current gcc" (I don't use Netbeans). I've added a simple replacement to the end of the answer though.

Comment: Thanks for the 'stoi' replacement. But now there's an error stating that there's a invalid conversion from int to char**.

Comment: @JoelSeah: I'll probably need to see your code to stand any chance of helping make sense of things.

Comment: It is the code that u gave me. The 'stoi' method as well as the bool operator.

Comment: Yes, the question is how your using it. As I've written things, there shouldn't be a conversion from int to anything, so you must be using it differently than intended.